# Deleted file from server using cuteftp.No local backup.How to restore

Tags: windows, hosting, dedicated-server, data-recovery

Files on server is deleted from my windows hosting server (Dedicated Hosting Server -Leaseweb.com).

I deleted files using cuteFTP.Can i recover files by logging in to my dedicated server remotely.

Does files deleted from FTP gets deleted completely.I tried to check recycle bin on server files are not there.

Comment: First make sure the disk get's no longer written to. Then ask your provider *first* and *as soon as possible* before trying anything by yourself. Quite surely they have a backup in place (depends on the exact kind of server), and better ask early enough before the files in question get rotated out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without backups, chances are slim that you can recover the file.

The only thing you can try is looking at a program that can undelete files from NTFS drives, most of which are pay-for, and hope nothing else has overwritten the sectors on which your file was saved in the first place. This can get even more..."interesting"...if this was a VM system.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the deleted file in your Queue Window, select Properties, copy the Temp Folder path and there you'll find your file.

Answer (score 1):

Short of running a data recovery application, your files are gone. You can always try something like [recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but there's no guarantee that you'll get anything.

The only guaranteed way to get your files back would be to restore them. Take this as a lesson of why backups are extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

Try the options offered by MarkM and Bart.  Failing that, ask your provider if they have a backup and would be willing to restore the file for you (expect to pay for this: It typically requires an actual person to do work for you).

Also take this important lesson to heart and ***make backups of any data you don't want to lose***.